# Qual a origem do verde na cultura hacker?

Tags: linux

Sempre que o tema "hacking" é retratado pelas mídias colocam caras anti-sociais em um terminal Preto em letras verdes.
Eu queria saber de onde vem sempre esse verde das letras. é algum simbólico?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nos anos 80, eram utilizados monitores de fósforo verde, e que frequentemente apresentavam 'fantasmas' na tela. Além de inspirar esse visual hacking, também inspirou aquele visual do matrix.

veja mais em: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_de_f%C3%B3sforo_verde